# Google Endpoint - java.sql.Timestamp - JSON

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

How to pass java.sql.Timestamp as JSON from front-end?
By default, I tried giving like 2015-09-29T12:30:00 in API explored.
It is not working.

Also, if anyone know, how to use @ApiTransformer for in-build java classes. OR is there an option to use this annotation at property level instead of POJO class level.

Answer:

```
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        String jacksonDate = mapper.writeValueAsString(timestamp);
        System.out.println("JSON Timestamp: "+jacksonDate);
        System.out.println("JAVA Timestamp: "+mapper.readValue(jacksonDate, Timestamp.class));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

output:
JSON Timestamp: 1443772585286
JAVA Timestamp: 2015-10-02 11:56:25.286

Even it accepts: yyyy-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to think doing the opposite.

Let's say you get values from database to java beans (POJO) and serialize them to JSON objects. Print them out especially Timestamp values.

Then use the same format values as a short-cut answer.

On the other hand, in Jackson, I know that java.sql.Date accepts "long" values of time measure. Timestamp may use the same approach. "time in milliseconds" is a long value though.

On the other hand if you look for handling marshalling and unmarshalling of types in Rest systems you can check this out.

http://www.developerscrappad.com/2308/java/java-ee/rest-jax-rs/java-rest-jax-rs-2-0-how-to-handle-date-time-and-timestamp-data-types/

Comment: Thanks a lot! GAE is using Jackson library as JSON parser. I tried converting timestamp to and from JSON in standalone program and found the format what Jackson expects.